# How to get a working EXE file using pyinstaller with the sounddevice module in Python

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Unfortunately pyinstaller has problem with the sounddevice module.

I wrote the code below, but when I make an EXE file using pyinstaller, the EXE file in the dist folder does not work. The making process using pyinstaller finishes successfully but the EXE file does not work.

The code is:

```
import sounddevice as sd

fs=44100
duration =2 # seconds
print('Start')
myrecording = sd.rec(duration * fs, samplerate=fs,    channels=2,dtype='float64')
sd.wait()
print('play')
sd.play(myrecording, fs)
print('end')
```

Comment: Output from pyinstaller?

Comment: This question is incomplete. What exactly does not work when running the executable? How did you use pyinstaller?

Comment: Do you run the executable in a console/command window? You'd see helpful error messages that you may miss by just double-clicking the executable.

Comment: Please run it in your own windows 10 system using console/command window using "pyinstaller mycode.py". I think you can't get true results in generated dist folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could the problem be that the program exits straight after you do `sd.play()`?

Try replacing that line with `sd.play(myrecording, fs, blocking=True)`

Also, sounddevice is not a perfect library, so you need to do a bit of extra tweaking to make it work:

In your directory where your EXE is located, add a directory called `_sounddevice_data` and put [this file](https://github.com/spatialaudio/portaudio-binaries/blob/master/libportaudio64bit.dll) into that folder (if you are using Python 64-bit) or [this](https://github.com/spatialaudio/portaudio-binaries/blob/master/libportaudio32bit.dll) one (if you are using Python 32-bit).

Try running the EXE, it should work!

Hope this helps!

Comment: @A.Keshavarz Can I ask, does it instantly close itself when you run it?

Comment: I replaced sd.play(myrecording, fs) with   sd.play(myrecording, fs, blocking=True), but it doesn't work again. I run it in  console/command window using  pyinstaller mycode.py  .

Comment: Yes, it instantly close itself when you run it

Comment: @A.Keshavarz I mean, when you click the .exe file, does it instantly exit, stay open for 2 seconds then exit, or stay open for 4 seconds then exit?

Comment: @A.Keshavarz Ok, are you sure it does not error, because it should stay open for at least 2 seconds if the code is correct. Try running the code in python (not pyinstaller) and tell me if it works.

Comment: when I click the exe file it instantly exits.

Comment: @A.Keshavarz try opening terminal (or cmd on windows) and running it from there, then post the results of what it outputs here.

Comment: The message is it can not load library

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\sounddevice.py", line 62, in <module>
OSError: cannot load library '<None>': error 0x7e

Comment: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "astack.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in

Comment: _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\keshavarz\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-pa

Comment: ckages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\sounddevice.py", line 73, in <module>
OSError: cannot load library 'C:\Users\Keshavarz\Desktop\dist\astack\_sounddevic
e_data\libportaudio32bit.dll': error 0x7e
[5084] Failed to execute script astack

Comment: @A.Keshavarz Check my edited answer, It should now work!

Comment: Exactly right. You are ingenious. I also have problems with "scipy.io.wavfile" and "scipy.io.wavfile" module when I use pyinstaller. Finally I removed scipy module from my code.  I do not want to miss you. Is it possible I have your email If it is possible? My Email is: ali.cho@yahoo.com

Comment: @A.Keshavarz Unfortunately, I cannot give you my email, but if the answer was correct, I would appreciate if you mark it as correct and give it an upvote!

Comment: Thanks again. I marked it as correct and upvoted it.

Comment: Hope you don't mind me bringing this back up, but would you know I could do this but with "--onefile" mode on pyinstaller? The problem there is the directory for "_sounddevice_data" is in a temp folder that only exists while the script is running, so there's no way for me to place the "libportaudio64bit.dll" file in there.

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer didn't work but helped.

For me, the working solution is to add **_sounddevice_data** folder where the .exe file is located then making a **portaudio-binaries** folder in it and finally putting **libportaudio64bit.dll** in the recently created folder.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Well, this answer is pretty close to what I need, since the error I get points out that the folder mentioned should be at the top level of the temporary folder that gets created in temp while the executable is running:

>>"OSError: cannot load library 'C:\Users\kim\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI107882\_sounddevice_data\portaudio-binaries\libportaudio64bit.dll': error 0x7e"<< 

BUT ... I am finding the the suggested solutions for copying an entire folder structure into the executable do not work. I only get the actual files. So I'm still hunting for a solution ...